# Deploying Container on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I am trying to deploy this app. https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-docker . This container is a collection of various images. It uses `docker-compose` to create the container. It is my understanding that this cannot be run as an image from a GCP Artifact Repo as a docker Image. This needs a VM perhaps?

My question is if there is a way to deploy this container as an Image in a serverless fashion in GCP or any other cloud platform. Any pointers/help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use Cloud Run (the most Serverless way) or on a VM.

On Cloud Run you can deploy a [single](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts) image as a Service (Cloud Run Terminology), if you have more than one image you can deploy multiple Services and make them talk to each other

Or on VM, that would be as if you are deploying on your personal laptop

Comment: The trouble is on cloud the VM is proving to be costly. With so many images you would have to deploy each one separately then configure each and everyone the way they are supposed to.. That is not practical in my particular use case. VM only remains the possible solution..it seems.